# How to allow a consumer of more precise type to be passed in as a consumer of a less precise type?

Tags: java, primitive, primitive-types, functional-interface, pecs

I have this following two functional interfaces:

**IndexBytePairConsumer.java**

```
package me.theeninja.nativearrays.core;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface IndexBytePairConsumer {
    void accept(long index, byte value);
}
```

**IndexIntPairConsumer.java**

```
package me.theeninja.nativearrays.core;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface IndexIntPairConsumer {
    void accept(long index, int value);
}
```

I also have the following method:

```
public void forEachIndexValuePair(IndexBytePairConsumer indexValuePairConsumer) {
    ...
}
```

**Is there any way I can allow an `IndexIntPairConsumer` to be passed in the above method (since a consumer of ints can accept bytes)?** I'm required to use primitives in the method signatures rather than the associated classes such as `Integer` and `Byte`, so any abstraction becomes much more difficult.

Comment: Perhaps define a generic IndexPairConsumer<T>?

Comment: @robinsax generics doesn't work with primitive types.

Comment: Simplest solution is to create another method that accept `IndexIntPairConsumer`.

Comment: @talex right, duh

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I invented for you.

Define

```
public interface IndexBytePairConsumer {
    void accept(long index, byte value);
}

public interface IndexIntPairConsumer extends IndexBytePairConsumer {
    default void accept(long index, byte value) {
        this.accept(index, (int) value);
    }

    void accept(long index, int value);
}
```

and you can use it

```
IndexIntPairConsumer c = (a,b)->{
    System.out.println(a + b);
};
forEachIndexValuePair(c);

forEachIndexValuePair((a, b) -> {
    System.out.println(a + b);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the type hierarchy (e.g. the way suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736780/2711488)), an adaptation step is unavoidable, as `IndexBytePairConsumer` and `IndexIntPairConsumer` are two different types. The smallest adaptation step would be

```
// given
IndexIntPairConsumer consumer = …

// call as
forEachIndexValuePair(consumer::accept);
```

As you said in your question, a consumer of ints can accept bytes, so the `accept` method of an `IndexIntPairConsumer` is a valid target for a method reference where an `IndexBytePairConsumer` is expected.